# Node JS mssql exporting database connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have hard time understanding why my code doesn't work. I am using node package mssql and want to have database pool connection initiation in separate file:

databaseConnection.js:

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

config = {
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
};

let pool = sql.connect(config);

module.exports = pool;
```

Then I have my express route file data.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../configs/databaseConnection");

router.get("/dataList", async (req, res) => {
  let allData = await db.request().query("select * from dataList");
  console.log(allData);
  res.render("dataList", { title: "Data list" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I start the server  and go to the route I get error:

```
(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.request is not a function
```

The thing is if I setup precisely as this example [mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait) (where verything would be done in the route) it works. However, if database connection is in separate file it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help understanding this

Regards,
Rokas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql.connect returns a promise, so once we know that, we can either do a  .then(result => ... or use await, for example:

If you want to store the db object at startup for later I'd suggest changing the line:

```
const db = require("../configs/databaseConnection");
```

to

```
let db = null; 
require("../configs/databaseConnection").then(pool => {
    db = pool;
});
```

Comment: But it is not an issue with promises, because when I print the '''db''' in the route it doesn't say undefined or pending Promise, but it has values. I think it something has to do how the sql object/class is created. Sadly I am not knowledge enough to understand this.

Comment: Oh that's strange.. when I do: db = require(./); console.log("DB:",db), I get the following: DB: Promise { <pending> }. And the error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.request is not a function suggests that we're dealing with a promise.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between the mssql documentation and the line in your db connection module. In the module the code is: let pool = sql.connect(config);, whereas in the mssql docs it's let pool = _await_ sql.connect(config); This is critical since it resolves the promise.